# Javascript click / touchstart not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a language selector on the top of my website, when I click it, it should show all the languages and when I click on the body it should disapear. Now the problem I have is that sometimes it just works perfect, but sometimes it doesn't work at all. On my mobile it more often doesn't work than it does.

This happends random, every time just refreshing the site will make it work again.

```
$('.topHeader ul li ul').hide();
$('html').on('click touchstart', function() {
    $('.topHeader ul li ul').hide();
});
$('.topHeader').on('click touchstart', function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('.topHeader ul li a').on('click touchstart', function() {
    $('.topHeader ul li ul').toggle();
});
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5gcdsjox/

I'm not using bootstrap, I just used some of the classes ;)

Comment: You need this: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @KWeiss Already have that, did not include the entire JS only the part that is important for this question. $(function() { /* CODE HERE */ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the list items take up 100% of the page's width, and you don't realize you are clicking on them rather than the area encompassed by the `html` selector.

Simply add this css, and it will illustrate what I mean...

```
.topHeader ul li ul li {
  background:azure;
}
```

A quick work-around is to make it that, by clicking on the list items you also hide the displayed items:

```
$('html').on('click touchstart', function() {
  $('.topHeader ul li ul').hide();
});
// I have added this extra handler
$('.topHeader ul li ul li').on('click touchstart', function() {
  $('.topHeader ul li ul').hide();
});
```

Edited jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0j9h1r2m/1/

Comment: Thank you for answering, the problem is that when clicking on English shoud show the submenu, now this is something that is not working correctly. On mobile clicking on English will give a background color change (did that in CSS), but will not show the submenu.